# He feels in a position to lend her money

Tags: collocations

Is that sentence idiomatic or it's possible to say it more natural?

> He **feels in a position to** lend her money.

Comment: It would work better if you inserted **himself** after **feels**.

Comment: I would tend to use "He *is/feels he **is/may be*** in a position to..." here.

Comment: "He feels he's in a position to..." seems to me the most natural way to say it.

Comment: He feels...  Does it mean that he considers... ?